# iterative lucas kanade optical flow

Tags: computer-vision, opticalflow

below is the algorithm I found online for iterative LK. I don't understand why in step 4 it only recalculate It and not Ix Iy?

From my understanding, the input are two images Im1, Im2, and velocity u v, the goal is to refine u and v because LK don't work well when movement is large.

For each point (x,y) in Im1, there's a corresponding u and v, so we move the window (for example, 3x3) in Im2 by u and v pixels from (x,y) to (x',y'). Now we have two windows, the first window is the one centered at (x,y) in Im1, and the second is the one centered at (x',y') in Im2, since (x',y') is not integer, we interpolate subpixel values in this window.

they we calculate delta_u and delta_v, using values from of two windows. However, the instruction says we should only use new It and not new Ix Iy.

[image]